# Mocha Error Output

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Whenever an exception is thrown in my Node application, mocha prints this exception in the console although those exceptions are intended since I want to provoke some edge scenarios.

I want Mocha only to print exception stack traces when a given test fails. If the test does not fail, this means that the exception was intended and therefore should not mess up the test report.

How can I achieve that? Is there a configuration for Mocha?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can see what the problem is exactly.

Comment: Please see here: https://gist.github.com/fb13/68025026aaf9235a88fd